# Can I use POJO in Hibernate Filter?

Tags: java, hibernate, pojo

Can I use Hibernate like this?

```
public class Employee{
  private String name;
  private String age;
  //public getters and setters
}

public class EmployeeDao{
  public List<Employee> getByFilter(Employee filter){
    //what whould I write here?
  }
}

public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Employee employeeFilter = new Employee();
    employeeFilter.setAge(15);
    List<Employee> employeesOf15 = new EmployeeDao().getByFilter(employeeFilter);
  }
}
```

If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your `getByFilter()` method, you could write a straightforward HQL or native SQL query to find all the employees who have an age equal to the filter's age, or use [Hibernate's Criteria Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html) like for example:

`return getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class).add(Restrictions.eq("age", filter.getAge())).list();`

It might be a good idea to add another parameter to your all-purpose `getByFilter()` method so you can specify filtering by any field (name, age, and so on), and then act accordingly.

Comment: Not exactly that I mean, @roy-six, but thank you. I don't want to add restrictions for every field in POJO. I want to set POJO as filter object and want Hibernate to find all non-null fields and their mappings to database in this POJO and make the request to database.

Comment: So I want to write `getSession().findByFilter(employee).list();` If employee contains only age, I want Hibernate to generate `WHERE age = :age`. But if employee also contains a name, I desire Hibernate to generate `WHERE age = :age AND name = :name`. Is it possible?

Comment: @omickron Nope..it's not possible....basically becouse...hibernate wouldn't know which kind of filters you want to apply (e.g. do you want all the not null fields in AND or any of them in OR)? I guess this is developer work..you know how to build the best query for your scenario...so you have to build it

Comment: It's a pity, @angelo-immediata. Thank's.